# while x is ValueError:

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have this code:

```
yon = raw_input("were you running in km y or n?: ")
if yon is "y":
    kilnumber = raw_input("how many kilometers?: ")
    milnumber = 0
    try:
        float(kilnumber)
    except:
        print "You must enter a number"
        exit()
```

I was hoping to make it simpler by adding a while loop to re-ask kilnumber if the user enters an illegal response. I was hoping for something like this:

```
yon = raw_input("were you running in km y or n?: ")
if yon is 'y':
    kilnumber = raw_input("how many kilometers?: ")
    milnumber = 0
    while float(kilnumber) is ValueError:
        print "You must enter a number"
        kilnumber = raw_input("how many kilometers?: ")
```

This code doesn't work because it sends an error message before evaluating the while loop. Solution?

Comment: Don't use `is` for comparing values, use `==`. Change the condition to `if yon == "y":`

Answer (score 6):

`float(kilnumber)` will never evaluate to `ValueError`. Rather, it may throw a `ValueError`. You need to catch it:

```
while True:
    try:
        float(kilnumber)
    except ValueError:
        # Not a valid number
        print "You must enter a number"
        kilnumber = raw_input("how many kilometers?: ")
    else:
        # No error; stop the loop
        break
```

See the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more on exceptions and errors.

Comment: when I try to run it the console prints: file "test.py", line 6 else: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Gingynator: That's because I screwed up the order of the clauses. It should be fixed now.

Comment: I followed your link to that tutorial and it actually had an exact example of what we were talking about :). to simplify you don't need an else, you can put break under try: after float(kilnumber) and it does the same thing. Thanks for help!

Comment: I propose to mark this one as solution

Answer (score 0):

What do you think this means?

```
while float(kilnumber) is ValueError:
```

`float(kilnumber)` will never be a `ValueError`, it can *throw* one. So you must use `try/catch`. You can put it into a `while` loop that checks a variable that indicates of correct data was entered.